# Solve a limit without L'Hopital: $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(\cos5x)}{\ln(\cos7x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, education, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve this limit without using L'Hopital's rule. I have attempted to solve this countless times, and yet, I seem to always end up with an equation that's far more complicated than the one I've started with.

$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(\cos5x)}{\ln(\cos7x)}$$

Could anyone explain me how to solve this without using L'Hopital's rule ? Thanks!

Comment: By [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}{{\frac{\ln(\cos(4x))}{\ln(\cos(3x))}}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513217/limit-evaluate-lim-x-to0-frac-ln-cos4x-ln-cos3x)

Answer (score 5):

Hint use the facts that 
$$\frac{\ln x}{x-1}\to 1$$ and 
$$\frac{1-\cos x }{x^2}\to \frac{1}{2}$$

Merry Christmas.

Comment: Thanks ^_^ , Merry Christmas to you as well :))

Comment: But how do you get that without L'Hopital?

Comment: @skan Can't you work it out ? I don't feel like writing more today, but look at some of my old answers to similar questions, you'll see the method.

Comment: @skan The first one is just $\ln'(1) = 1.$ The second one follows from $\sin x/x \to 1;$ undoubtedly you have seen this before.

Comment: @zhw yes I've seen that but I got it with L'Hopital.

Comment: @skan Sorry. Do you mean how do you get the limits I quoted ? They are basic, you need these limits in order to prove the derivatives of log and sin are what they are, so using hospital on them is circular.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Note that we have

$$\cos(n x)=1-2\sin^2(nx/2)$$

and

$$ \log(\cos(nx))=\frac{\log(1-2\sin^2(nx/2)}{2\sin^2(nx/2)}\, \frac{2\sin^2(nx/2)}{(nx/2)^2} (nx/2)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x \to 0  \to \ln(1+x)\sim x\\ x \to 0 \to cos(ax)\sim1-\frac{1}{2}(ax)^2\\ 
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (\cos 5x)}{\ln (\cos 7x)}=\\
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (1-\frac{1}{2}(5x)^2)}{\ln (1-\frac{1}{2}(7x)^2)}=\\
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(5x)^2}{-\frac{1}{2}(7x)^2}=\\\frac{25}{49}$$

Comment: $u~v$ doesn't implie $\ ln(u)~\ln(v).$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\ln(\cos(X))=\ln(1+(\cos(X)-1))\sim \cos(X)-1\sim \frac{-X^2}{2}\;(X\to 0)$$

thus the limit is $$\frac{25}{49}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cauchy's mean value theorem, but in fact that's kind of cheating, as this is how L' Hopital's rule is proved.

For every $x$ around 0 there exists by Cauchy's mean value theorem a $\vert \xi_x \vert \leq \vert x \vert$ such that

$$\frac{\ln(\cos(5x))}{\ln(\cos(7x))} 
= \frac{\ln(\cos(5x)) - \ln(\cos(0))}{\ln(\cos(7x))- \ln(\cos(0))}
= \frac{\left( \frac{-5\sin(5\xi_x)}{\cos(5\xi_x)} \right)}{\left( \frac{-7\sin(7\xi_x)}{\cos(7\xi_x)} \right)}
= \frac{5}{7}\frac{\cos(7\xi_x)}{\cos(5\xi_x)}\cdot \frac{\sin(5\xi_x)}{\sin(7\xi_x)}.$$

As $\xi_x\rightarrow 0$ for $x\rightarrow 0$, we get (if the respective limits exist)

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(\cos(5x))}{\ln(\cos(7x))} 
= \lim_{\xi \rightarrow 0} \frac{5}{7}\frac{\cos(7\xi_x)}{\cos(5\xi_x)}\cdot \frac{\sin(5\xi_x)}{\sin(7\xi_x)}
=\lim_{\xi \rightarrow 0} \frac{5}{7} \frac{\sin(5\xi_x)}{\sin(7\xi_x)}.$$

Repeating the argument for $\frac{\sin(5\xi_x)}{\sin(7\xi_x)}$ yields that the limit equals $\frac{25}{49}$.